# Silverstripe 3 Extending Upload Field with nice error messages

Tags: silverstripe

I've made a custom upload field to extract zip files automatically. I can't figure out how to throw 'nice' error messages that are readable to a end-user.

I want the errors to come from the saveTemporaryFile method.

eg (something like this would be great):

return $this->setError("My custom error");

Answer (score 0):

Error messages are usually thrown in the `validate` function where you have access to the form field's `Validator` object. For instance:

```
<?php

class MyUploadField extends UploadField {

    // ...

    private $temporaryFileSaveSuccessful = false;

    private function saveTemporaryFile() {
        // Do extract logic
        // set $this->temporaryFileSaveSuccessful appropriately
    }

    public function validate($validator) {
        if(!$this->temporaryFileSaveSuccessful) {
            $validator->validationError('ExtractionUnsuccessful',
                'Unable to extract your zip file',
                'validation'
            );
            return false;
        }

        return parent::validate($validator);
    }

    // ...

}
```

However this has the one issue that the `validate` function is called on form submission, so depending on your code `saveTemporaryFile` may not have been run by that time. You could possibly run the extraction earlier by creating a `Form` subclass and overriding the `httpSubmission` function.